# Run a Ruby or Python script from iruby or ipython notebook?

Tags: python, ruby, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to run a Ruby program with iruby? I want to run a script instead of entering my code in iruby notebook console.

I assume that iruby would be the same with ipython.

Comment: `require './your_program'`?

Comment: LoadError: cannot load such file -- main

Answer (score 0):

Require `./your_program` works well for me